# Is it possible to have custom ansible modules grouped in only one folder and have them available for all playbooks in other folders?

Tags: ansible

I am managing a repository of Ansible playbooks.

Every playbook ( `playbooks/tool_*/playbook_*.yml` ) stands in a dedicated folder, which also hosts auxiliary files such as variables playbooks, Jinja2 templates, HTML templates and Ansible custom modules.

So it looks like this:

```
playbooks
├── tool_1
│   ├── library
│   │   ├── ansible_custom_module_1.py
│   │   └── ansible_custom_module_2.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── vars
│   │   └── ...
│   └── playbook_1.yml
├── tool_2
│   ├── library
│   │   ├── ansible_custom_module_1.py
│   │   ├── ansible_custom_module_2.py
│   │   └── ansible_custom_module_3.py
└── tool_3
    └── ...
```

The ansible custom modules are called in the playbook in this way:

```yaml
- name: do the custom task n1
  ansible_custom_module_1: 
    input1: ...
    input2: ...
    input3: ...
```

Now, I would like to have all the ansible custom modules in only one folder `playbooks/ansible_custom_modules/library/`,
so that I can remove all the folders `playbooks/tool_*/library/` and thus avoid to have duplicates of the same file.

What do I have to do to be able to call the ansible custom modules in `playbooks/ansible_custom_modules/library/` from the playooks `playbooks/tool_*/playbook_*.yml`?

Is this even possible?

I have looked the matter up in [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html), but I have found this statement which seems to suggest that such a folder structure cannot let the playbooks to retrieve ansible custom modules.

> To create a module:
>
> Create a library directory in your workspace, your test play *[i.e. the ansible trial custom module]* should
> live in the same directory.

### What I tried

I created a symbolink link pointing from the playbook library foledr to the "centralized" library folder as following

```
ll playbooks/tool_1/library/

library -> playbooks/ansible_custom_modules/library
```

but it seems that the playbook ignores it:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'ansible_custom_module_1'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/.../playbooks/tool_1/playbook_1.yml': line 319, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: do the custom task n1
      ^ here
```

The same is if the symbolik link is created on the custom modules files and not on the `library` folder

```
ll playbooks/tool_1/library/

ansible_custom_module_1.py -> playbooks/ansible_custom_modules/library/ansible_custom_module_1.py

ansible_custom_module_2.py -> playbooks/ansible_custom_modules/library/ansible_custom_module_2.py
```

Comment: put them in a collection.

Comment: ansible collection is your friend and provides a structure like this for you https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections_structure.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the page *[adding standalone local modules for all playbooks and roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-standalone-local-modules-for-all-playbooks-and-roles)* of the documentation.

> To load standalone local modules automatically and make them available to all playbooks and roles, use the [DEFAULT_MODULE_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-module-path) configuration setting or the `ANSIBLE_LIBRARY` environment variable. The configuration setting and environment variable take a colon-separated list, similar to `$PATH`.

So, one of the many solutions is to have a configuration in `~/.ansible.cfg` stating:

```ini
[defaults]
library = /path/to/that/folder/called/playbooks/ansible_custom_modules/library
```

There are tons of other variations of the same idea.
As long as you know:

- where the configuration file could be:

  > - `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (environment variable if set)
  > - `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
  > - `~/.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
  > - `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

  *<sup>Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file</sup>*
- that the configuration could set either by the environment variable `ANSIBLE_LIBRARY` or via a configuration settings in the section `[defaults]` under the key `library`
- and [how relative path are behaving in the configuration file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#relative-paths-for-configuration)

Then you can definitely come up with a combination that would fit your needs.